# All vagrant PHP CLI scripts hang waiting on host resolution on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I've been getting hangs when executing PHP commands on my Homestead vagrant box running Ubuntu. There is a significant lag before the console even starts the php cli execution.

Ran `strace -vyT -S time php artisan help` from vagrant box. Everything gets stuck for several minutes on the first to last call to `recvfrom(3`, but I have no idea why:

```
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000010>
fstat(3</run/resolvconf/resolv.conf>, {st_dev=makedev(0, 16), st_ino=7632, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=171, st_atime=2015/10/17-04:53:56, st_mtime=2015/10/17-04:53:54, st_ctime=2015/10/17-04:53:54}) = 0 <0.000007>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fed9385c000 <0.000008>
read(3</run/resolvconf/resolv.conf>, "# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file fo"..., 4096) = 171 <0.000010>
read(3</run/resolvconf/resolv.conf>, "", 4096) = 0 <0.000006>
close(3</run/resolvconf/resolv.conf>)   = 0 <0.000008>
munmap(0x7fed9385c000, 4096)            = 0 <0.000011>
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="homestead", release="3.13.0-65-generic", version="#106-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:08:27 UTC 2015", machine="x86_64", domainname="(none)"}) = 0 <0.000006>
stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_dev=makedev(0, 16), st_ino=7632, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=171, st_atime=2015/10/17-04:53:56, st_mtime=2015/10/17-04:53:54, st_ctime=2015/10/17-04:53:54}) = 0 <0.000008>
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3 <0.000009>
fstat(3</etc/hosts>, {st_dev=makedev(8, 1), st_ino=1161, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=251, st_atime=2015/10/16-18:57:29, st_mtime=2014/10/03-01:16:42, st_ctime=2014/10/03-01:16:42}) = 0 <0.000005>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fed9385c000 <0.000008>
read(3</etc/hosts>, "127.0.0.1 localhost\n\n# The follo"..., 4096) = 251 <0.000009>
read(3</etc/hosts>, "", 4096)           = 0 <0.000007>
close(3</etc/hosts>)                    = 0 <0.000007>
munmap(0x7fed9385c000, 4096)            = 0 <0.000010>
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3 <0.000012>
fcntl(3<socket:[78362]>, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0 <0.000006>
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress) <0.000094>
select(4, [3<socket:[78362]>], [3<socket:[78362]>], [3<socket:[78362]>], {0, 200000}) = 1 (out [3], left {0, 199997}) <0.000010>
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0 <0.000007>
fcntl(3<socket:[78362]>, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY) = 0 <0.000006>
setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 0 <0.000008>
write(3<socket:[78362]>, "478\0<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding"..., 483) = 483 <0.000042>
brk(0x2f93000)                          = 0x2f93000 <0.000472>
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <4.940291>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.072574>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.033758>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.038904>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.026003>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.024057>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.055221>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.058240>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.027569>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.056877>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.025934>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.076699>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.089092>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.254680>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.131634>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.065721>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.042778>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.072277>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.044424>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set) <0.080704>
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) <113.777721>
```

Here is the contents of `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
127.0.1.1 homestead homestead
```

The contents of `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

The problem is now affecting EVERY unrelated vagrant box I have, not just the Homestead box. Almost every PHP command on each box is stalled by 5-15 minutes for each CLI execution. If a chain of commands must be called, it can take an hour to finish a process that should take 30 seconds.

This started after the Mac these boxes are run on was upgraded to El Capitan.

Depending on the vagrant box, sometimes this strace line:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
```

Is replaced by:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.56.1")}, 16) = 0
```

The IP 192.168.56.1 appears to be the default router for VirtualBox.

Please note, all vagrant boxes are either standard config or those that work without issue on my other team member's Mac/Windows systems.

Vagrant 1.7.4 and VirtualBox 4.3.30.

In response to request `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Results for `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 9000`:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1317/hhvm
```

Why hhvm is showing up, I don't know, because the box is supposed to be using the standard PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: I blame xdebug client. Try to disable xdebug on Ubuntu.

**My rationale**:

I don't see any problems with host resolution in the strace log there.

It checks `/etc/resolv.conf` first, then `/etc/hosts` and connects to 127.0.0.1:9000 `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress) <0.000094>`

Port 9000 is the default for xdebug, unless redefined in `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` or similar.

`write(3<socket:[78362]>, "478\0<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding"..., 483) = 483 <0.000042>` looks like a message sent from xdebug extension to the client.

It waits for 2 minutes `recvfrom(3, 0x7ffc489b16d0, 128, 0, 0, 0) = ? ERESTARTSYS`, then gives up and execute your php script.

The wait time has been reduced to 200 ms since v2.2.4: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/90

Assuming that disabling of xdebug resolve the problem, there are few options:

- upgrade xdebug
- configure xdebug to start on-demand only with `xdebug.remote_autostart=off`
- keep enabling/disabling xdebug
- keep xdebug client always on and ensure ports are mapped correctly and it does not hung

Comment: It was Xdebug conflicting with HHVM's port 9000. Using Xdebug 2.3.2 already. Need `xdebug.remote_autostart=on` because I frequently use PHPStorm's xdebug connection for debugging, so I tried just changing the Xdebug port to 9001 to eliminate the port conflict with HHVM. This fixed the problem. No idea why this suddenly started being a problem when it wasn't before, but glad it's resolved!

Comment: Randomly started happening again even after making the port changes, but hanging for upward of 50 minutes unless I totally disable xdebug. Tried removing HHVM entirely then upgraded to `xdebug-2.4.0rc3` and did a full system restart. Was still hanging. Eventually discovered that disabling `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` fixes the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related to hostname resolve. if you are trying use your ip instead of localhost ip `127.0.0.1`. better to use  in `/etc/hosts` like :

```
yourip  hostname.example.com hostname
```

for example

```
10.0.2.20 test.example.com test
```

and remove `localhost` related from `/etc/hosts` or keep at last. system will try to take first entry and if you are not using `ipv6` then you can remove ipv6 related entry also.

**EDIT:**
your `/etc/resolv.conf` file should have bellow line

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

also add vagrant default network because your output shows it trying to connect that but if you don't want to use then you can skip. you are using `127.0.0.1` so at least it should be there.you can take help for changing from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Not sure I follow. This is on a vagrant installation. It will always be localhost and inaccessible to the outside world. There are no other IPs for me to specify for this isolated test environment that I know of.

Comment: if you use `10.0..2.20 test.example.com test` then you will only accessible from host not from outside world. bcoz ip 10.0.2.20 is private ip. if you type in hosts browser http://test.example.com it will open and if you try to access from other host you will not be able to access .

Comment: why would I specifically change the address to 10.0.2.20 over standard 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Please see update to bottom of original post. This doesn't appear related to the default config of my vagrant boxes themselves.

Comment: i changed my answer please try that . i am not getting why your resolv.conf have `nameserver 10.0.2.3` are you using any interface in 10.0.2.3 related to this. first try edited solution if not work then give me output of `route -n `  and `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 9000`.

Comment: The address `10.0.2.3` appears to just be the most recent nameserver written to resolv.conf. I have never edited that file before. See added details in my post.

Comment: your hhvm is running . have you tried adding nameserver for 127.0.0.1 and test still hang.

Comment: if your are not using hhvm then kill that process using command `kill pid `  like ` kill 1317 `  or `kill -9 1317`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92864/discussion-between-pl-rock-and-ecomevo).

Comment: got time to continue on this one? If so, see chat responses.

Answer (score 0):

Well it feels like a DNS problem.  My guess would be either your machine can't resolve DNS via the given host name, or the DNS server is just slow.  My advice would be to install a caching DNS server locally, and use that, and add to the /etc/hosts file anything in a private network, that won't be served from DNS.  Use NetworkManager or whichever network service you have to add 127.0.0.1 as a viable (and preferred) DNS server, and things should work smoothly.  If you're using ubuntu, that should be as easy as sudo apt-get install bind9.

If you want to diagnose the problem, first install dnsutils, to get dig and nslookup, and try querying something, like www.google.co.uk, see how long it takes and which server is authoritative.  Then try using dig, to be more specific, interrogate the server directly, interrogate the SOA directly, see if you can figure out where the weakest link is.

It's probably a router that's advertising itself as DNS service via DHCP, but isn't working right when pressed.